# Where to get help with MiKTeX install error?

Tags: miktex

For days now I have troubleshooted an error when trying to install MiKTeX. I know this is off topic here, so I'm asking where can I post to get an answer? I have googled and found old posts with random suggestions that have not worked.[image: MiKTeX install error]

Comment: Did you try asking at [MiKTeX.org](https://miktex.org/help)?  Do you have a .log file in `C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log`? Also, maybe  there's a problem with your antivirus or your firewall?

Comment: Looks as if some end-of-installation configuration didn't work. It could be e.g. fc-cache that failed due to some problematic font. Ignore the error for now and check if miktex works. If some configuration is missing you normally can execute it later.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I think you're right about a problematic font because I installed new fonts a few days before I updated. Then I hit the error and then I couldn't typeset. I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling. I even deleted the font I though was troublesome. I pushed through the error and I'm able to typeset again.

Comment: You can try `fc-cache -f -v` on a command line, perhaps you can then see which font is problematic.

Comment: I said it before, and I'll say it again: Try the portable version of MikTeX, which does not have issues with permissions. Also, if you might be behind a firewall, be sure that you get packages via https rather than ftp, by manually selecting a download source. Finally, make a zip file of the working portable installation. Then, in case a change corrupts it, you can revert.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's off-topic here, but you can always try the [MiKTeX mailing list](https://miktex.org/list).